# ajax submitting forms using FormData that contains Data & files

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax, multipartform-data

I was trying to submit a form that contains data & files

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
  var formData = $('form').serializeArray();
  formData.push({
    name: "logo",
    value: $("#wizard-picture")[0].files[0]
  });
  formData.push({
    name: "prologo",
    value: $("#wizard-picturep")[0].files[0]
  });
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    formData.push({
      name: "Keys",
      value: list[i]
    });
  }
  console.log(formData);
  $.ajax({
    url: '/Company/Steps/',
    method: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(data) {
      debugger;
      alert("succses");
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      debugger;
      console.log(xhr);
      console.log(ajaxOptions);
      console.log(thrownError);

      alert(xhr.status);
      alert(thrownError);
    }
  });
});
```

the formData is correctly shown all data in the console. but on my controller it is null !!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To send file data in a request you need to use a `FormData` object, not a serialised array.

As such, you can provide a reference to your `form` element to the constructor of `FormData`, like this:

```js
$('form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var formData = new FormData($('form').get());

  $.ajax({
    url: '/Company/Steps/',
    method: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(data) {
      debugger;
      alert("succses");
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      debugger;
      console.log(xhr);
      console.log(ajaxOptions);
      console.log(thrownError);
    }
  });
});
```